# Can't find variable: setImmediate (Error)

Tags: android, react-native

Seeing the `Can't find variable: setImmediate` on my emulator when attempting to `react-native run-android` after the `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 38s` and my emulator loads up the app.

I do not use `setImmediate` anywhere and the error message only appears on the emulator not in my console windows. It does not show where exactly the error appears.

my cli shows

```
info Reloading app...
[Sat May 30 2020 14:36:08.579]  BUNDLE  ./index.js
```

I have tried the following to resolve this

- by removing `node_modules` and reinstalling via `npm install`
- deleteing `android\app\src\main\res\raw`
- executing `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease`
- executing `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleDebug`
- deleting `android/app/build`
- building in android studio (it does not show any problems in android studio)

My external imports are:

```
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
```

once again. I do not have `setImmediate` anywhere in my code.

Using React:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
```

`setImmediate` occurencies in my `node_modules`

```
.\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-runtime\lib\runtime-corejs2-definitions.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-runtime\lib\runtime-corejs3-definitions.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\@jest\environment\build\index.d.ts (2 hits)
.\node_modules\@jest\fake-timers\build\jestFakeTimers.d.ts (1 hit)
.\node_modules\@jest\fake-timers\build\jestFakeTimers.js (14 hits)
.\node_modules\@react-native-community\eslint-config\index.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\array-includes\test.html (50 hits)
.\node_modules\asap\browser-raw.js (8 hits)
.\node_modules\asap\raw.js (6 hits)
.\node_modules\asap\README.md (10 hits)
.\node_modules\async\asyncify.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\async\CHANGELOG.md (5 hits)
.\node_modules\async\dist\async.js (25 hits)
.\node_modules\async\dist\async.min.js (6 hits)
.\node_modules\async\dist\async.min.map (3 hits)
.\node_modules\async\ensureAsync.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\async\index.js (9 hits)
.\node_modules\async\internal\queue.js (7 hits)
.\node_modules\async\internal\setImmediate.js (7 hits)
.\node_modules\async\memoize.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\async\nextTick.js (12 hits)
.\node_modules\async\priorityQueue.js (6 hits)
.\node_modules\async\setImmediate.js (9 hits)
.\node_modules\async\transform.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\async\wrapSync.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\asynckit\bench.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\asynckit\lib\defer.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\co\History.md (4 hits)
.\node_modules\connect\HISTORY.md (2 hits)
.\node_modules\connect\index.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\bower.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\core.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\core.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\core.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\library.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\library.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\library.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\fn\set-immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\set-immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\web.immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\_microtask.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\_task.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\modules\web.immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\modules\_microtask.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\modules\_task.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\core-js\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\core-js\README.md (12 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\core.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\core.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\core.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\library.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\library.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\library.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.min.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\client\shim.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\fn\set-immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\set-immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.microtask.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.task.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\web.immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\modules\$.microtask.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\modules\$.task.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\modules\web.immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\core-js\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\CHANGELOG.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\Promise.native.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\Promise.native.js.flow (2 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\resolveImmediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\resolveImmediate.js.flow (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\setImmediate.js (4 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\lib\setImmediate.js.flow (5 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\module-map.json (2 hits)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\node_modules\fbjs\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\create-react-class\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\envinfo\dist\envinfo.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\errorhandler\index.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\external-editor\main\index.js (7 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\globals\globals.json (2 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\rxjs.umd.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\rxjs.umd.js.map (2 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\rxjs.umd.min.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\rxjs.umd.min.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\internal\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\Immediate.d.ts (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\Immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\scheduler\AsapAction.ts (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\util\Immediate.ts (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\_esm2015\internal\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\_esm2015\internal\util\Immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\util\Immediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint-plugin-jest\rules\__tests__\valid-describe.test.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\eslint-plugin-react-native-globals\index.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\expect\build-es5\index.js (23 hits)
.\node_modules\expect\build-es5\index.js.map (18 hits)
.\node_modules\external-editor\main\index.js (6 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\Promise.native.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\Promise.native.js.flow (2 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\resolveImmediate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\resolveImmediate.js.flow (1 hit)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\setImmediate.js (4 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\lib\setImmediate.js.flow (5 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\module-map.json (2 hits)
.\node_modules\fbjs\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\fbjs-scripts\CHANGELOG.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\fbjs-scripts\third-party-module-map.json (6 hits)
.\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\fs-extra\CHANGELOG.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\globals\globals.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\jest-util\build\installCommonGlobals.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\jsdom\Changelog.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\file-api\FileReader-impl.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\pify\readme.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro\node_modules\fs-extra\CHANGELOG.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Serializers\sourceMapGenerator.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Serializers\sourceMapGenerator.js.flow (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro-source-map\src\source-map.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro-source-map\src\source-map.js.flow (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro-symbolicate\src.real\__tests__\__fixtures__\directory\subdir1\bar.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro-symbolicate\src.real\__tests__\__fixtures__\hermes.js.hbc.map (2 hits)
.\node_modules\metro-symbolicate\src.real\__tests__\__fixtures__\hermescjs.js.hbc.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\metro-symbolicate\src.real\__tests__\__fixtures__\testfile.sectioned.js.map (3 hits)
.\node_modules\on-finished\index.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\path-type\node_modules\pify\readme.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\pify\readme.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\pn\scripts\generate.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\pn\test\timers.js (4 hits)
.\node_modules\pn\timers.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\prettier\index.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\promise\build.js (4 hits)
.\node_modules\promise\Readme.md (3 hits)
.\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\node-extensions.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\backend.js (8 hits)
.\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\standalone.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\flow\jest.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\StatusBar\StatusBar.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpTimers.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js (10 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Interaction\InteractionManager.js (5 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\Data\LogBoxData.js (3 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Promise.js (4 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\promiseRejectionIsError.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Storage\AsyncStorage.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\Data\YellowBoxRegistry.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\views\picker\ReactPicker.java (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\views\picker\ReactPickerManager.java (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native\ReactCommon\hermes\inspector\tools\msggen\yarn.lock (4 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\createHandler.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\core\AnimatedNode.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-native-sqlite-storage\lib\sqlite.core.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.development.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.production.min.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\react-test-renderer\umd\react-test-renderer.development.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\react-test-renderer\umd\react-test-renderer.production.min.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\request\lib\helpers.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\CHANGELOG.md (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\es6\rsvp.es.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\es6\rsvp.es.map (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.es.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.es.map (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.map (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rsvp\lib\rsvp\asap.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.js (8 hits)
.\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.min.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\Rx.js (40 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\Rx.js.map (40 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\Rx.min.js (27 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\Rx.min.js.map (13 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\scheduler\AsapAction.js.map (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\src\scheduler\AsapAction.ts (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\src\util\Immediate.ts (40 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\util\Immediate.d.ts (7 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\util\Immediate.js (39 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\util\Immediate.js.map (40 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\_esm2015\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\_esm2015\util\Immediate.js (39 hits)
.\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\scheduler\AsapAction.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\util\Immediate.js (39 hits)
.\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\sane\src\poll_watcher.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\sane\src\watchexec_watcher.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\setimmediate\package.json (17 hits)
.\node_modules\setimmediate\setImmediate.js (6 hits)
.\node_modules\source-map-resolve\lib\source-map-resolve-node.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\source-map-resolve\package.json (1 hit)
.\node_modules\source-map-resolve\readme.md (2 hits)
.\node_modules\source-map-resolve\source-map-resolve.js (1 hit)
.\node_modules\source-map-support\browser-source-map-support.js (2 hits)
.\node_modules\uglify-es\tools\domprops.json (2 hits)
.\node_modules\uglify-es\tools\exit.js (1 hit)
```

[Can't find variable: setImmediate (Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwCtY.png)

Comment: Can you search for setImmediate ocurrencies inside your node_modules folder? That can show the potential cause of your problem by showing what depency is calling that method

Comment: @RanderGabriel Hi, thank you for your reply. Added it to the question.